# Eclipse Kepler crashes without any log entry

Tags: 13.10, java, android, eclipse, crash

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander 64bit and Eclipse Kepler 64bit terminates after some random time without response. The windows simply disappears.

There's also no entry about the crash in .metadata/.log

Comment: you are not alone - get the same behaviour. It crashes regularly

Comment: i read somewhere that there is problem with nvidia driver and eclipse ui dont know how is related but at home i use intel video card and eclipse has never crashed, buuut at work i have nvidia video card and eclipse crashes 5-6 times every day its just madnes (angry)

Comment: Same issue with Intel and Nvidia.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem (Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit, Eclipse Kepler, Intel Sandybridge Mobile graphics) and this helped:

Put inside `eclipse.ini`:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

[Thanks to NVK.](http://wyldeplayground.net/eclipse-kepler-crashes-without-any-log-entry/)